# Syntax Error in From clause Deleting record with ADO

Tags: sql, ms-access, ado, syntax-error

I'm using ADO to delete a record in my MS Access 2007 database and am at a total loss as to why I'm getting this syntax error for my SQL code.  It claims there is an error in the FROM clause but I do not see it.  I have taken the FROM clause directly from a working SQL statement in another module using the same table.  I've entered the code into the SQL View of a new query and it runs just fine.  Here is the code:

```
Private Sub cmdDeleteMessage_Click()

  If MsgBox("Once you delete a message, it cannot be undone." & _ 
     "Are you sure you want to delete this message?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    Dim sql As String
    Dim rsDel As New ADODB.Recordset
    rsDel.CursorType = adOpenDynamic
    rsDel.LockType = adLockOptimistic
    sql = "DELETE * FROM [Staff Notes] WHERE [MsgID] = " & Me.txtMsgID.Value & ";"

    rsDel.Open sql, CurrentProject.AccessConnection, , , adCmdTable

      With rsDelete
          .Update
          .Close
      End With
  End If

End Sub
```

And Ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to run an action query but using a recordset (which expects a select query).

Try this:

```
sql = "DELETE * FROM [Staff Notes] WHERE [MsgID] = " & Me.txtMsgID.Value & ";"
CurrentProject.AccessConnection.Execute sql, , adExecuteNoRecords
```

Also, if [MsgID] is a string, you need to enclose your value in quotes:

```
sql = "DELETE * FROM [Staff Notes] WHERE [MsgID] = " & Chr$(34) & Me.txtMsgID.Value & Chr$(34) & ";"
```

Comment: It works! Cheers! I originally tried a select and then delete on the record and was getting the same result. I'm still confused as to why I can add records to a recordset but am unable to delete them. The only real difference I can see is that I didn't use a SQL statement to open the table which I wished to add to. Guess that makes all the difference. Anyway, thanks for the help!